# Mongoose: how to insert a field/value into an existing subdocument

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am having trouble understanding how new `field:value` `objects` are added to `mongo` databases.

Say I have the following `document`:

```
var people={'firstname': 'John','surname':'Smith',
'favouritefood':[{'fruit':'apples','drink':'coffee'}]}
```

how do I add 'vegetable':'broccoli' to 'favourite food' so it looks like this:

```
{'firstname': 'John','surname':'Smith',
'favouritefood':[{'fruit':'apples','drink':'coffee','vegetable':'broccoli'}]}
```

If I type:

```
people.findOneAndUpdate({'firstname':'John'},
{$push {favouritefood: {vegetable:broccoli}}},
{upsert:true})
```

it gives me this:

```
{'firstname': 'John','surname':'Smith',
'favouritefood':[{'fruit':'apples','drink':'coffee'},{'vegetable':'broccoli'}]}
```

and if I try:

```
people.findOneAndUpdate({'favoritefood':'apples'},
{$push {vegetable:broccoli}}},
{upsert:true})
```

it says:

```
'$push' is empty. You must specify a field like so: {$push: {<field>: ...}}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Cause the query condition {'favoritefood':'apples'} will not match a value. The $push operator appends a specified value to an array. But actually you want add value
to {'fruit':'apples','drink':'coffee'} which is not an Array. If possible,
make mirror change to document structure as ```favouritefood: [ { 'fruit':'apples'}, { 'drink':'coffee' }]```, then your code will work.

Comment: I guess I'll have to do that. But it just seems strange that you are given the ability to create something like `favouritefood: [ { 'fruit':'apples',  'drink':'coffee' }]` but then not to edit it.

Comment: What I mean is that you re-design your document structure as each item { 'fruit':'apples'} will be an element in favouritefood. The code I paste is manually changed :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will be able to update the favouritefood array first object following [this](http://mongoblog.tumblr.com/post/21792332279/updating-one-element-in-an-array) syntax

But i suggest you the same that people in the comments, change your structure to one more natural in mongoDB. Consider each category of food as an element of the array not an object field of the first element.

Comment: I understand the comments and will follow them, but I don't think the way I've set it up is somehow unusual. After all, embedding is anticipated and encouraged and there are even examples in http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/ which contemplate a very similar setup.

Comment: This is how I finally did it `people.findOneAndUpdate({'favoritefood.fruit':'apples'},
{$set {'favorite.$.vegetable':'broccoli'}}},
{upsert:true})`